# How to insert full content of regex data into wordpress database via PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to insert new post to WORDPRESS using PHP. So this is my code.

I'm using regex to get the data I want and insert it into the database when I run it without insert into the database, its working fine. But whenI try to insert, my code inserts only the last image files...It's must be "x" file.

```
<?
$link = 'http://example.com/index.html';
$get = file_get_contents($link);
//get title
if (preg_match_all('/title="RSS 2.0" href="...........................(.*).html/',$get,$title))
foreach($title[1] as $orgtitle)
{
    $title = str_replace("-"," Vol.","$orgtitle");
    echo $title."\n";
}
//get content
if (preg_match_all('/<span class = "photoThum" ><a href="(.*?)"/',$get,$description))
foreach($description[1] as $content)
{
    $content = str_replace("http://","https://","$content");
    $content2 = '<img src= "'.$content.'" />'."\r\n";
    echo $content2;
}
//mysql connect
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "test";
$dbname = "test";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_posts (post_title, post_content, post_status, post_excerpt, to_ping, pinged, post_content_filtered)
VALUES ('$title', '$content2', 'draft', '', '', '', '')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Am i doing wrong anything ?

Answer (score 0):

`wp-load.php` is responsible for bootstrapping the WordPress environment which makes the plugin able to use the native WordPress Core function.

```
<?php
include 'wp-load.php';

$link = 'http://example.com/index.html';
$get = file_get_contents($link);

//get title
if (preg_match_all('/title="RSS 2.0" href="...........................(.*).html/',$get,$title))
foreach($title[1] as $orgtitle){
    $title = str_replace("-"," Vol.","$orgtitle"); 
}
//get content
if (preg_match_all('/<span class = "photoThum" ><a href="(.*?)"/',$get,$description))


foreach($description[1] as $content){
    $content = str_replace("http://","https://","$content");

    $content2 = '<img src= "'.$content.'" />'."\r\n";

    $post_id = wp_insert_post(
        array(
            'comment_status'    =>      'closed',
            'ping_status'       =>      'closed',
            'post_title'        =>      $title,     // Enter you title
            'post_content'      =>      $content2,
            'post_status'       =>      'publish',
            'post_type'         =>      'YOUR_POST_TYPE_NAME'   // Enter your posttype name
        )
    );

    echo "post_id :".$post_id."<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Well,its give me Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in and Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: I've solve the problem but,the regex data in $content2 should be 80 images,but in the contents the scripts insert,its only 1 img(the last one '80.jpg')..any ideas?

Comment: @Enuma Can you please add `.` before `=` operator. **Example:** `$content2 .= '<img src= "'.$content.'" />'."\r\n";` ?

Comment: Ok,let's me give it a try !

Comment: Error : Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 805309709 bytes)

Comment: My code : $content = str_replace("http://www.","https://","$content");
    $content2 .= '<img src= "'.$content.'" />'."\r\n";
    $content2 = mysql_real_escape_string($content2);

Comment: @Enuma have you insert in `foreach` loop ?

Comment: @Enuma Would you please tell me what is your file location you have written this code? I mean like `wp-content/theme/`

Comment: I write it in the root directory !

Comment: @Enuma did you mean WordPress root directory right https://www.screencast.com/t/UiEMlFmLJKz ?

Comment: Yes indeed ! That's the place i create the file !

Comment: @Enuma Okay give me few minutes I will create full code and update you shortly.

Comment: Hmm..your code don't need to connect database server? well,its working good,but something is wrong !!! i've set the post_type to "post" and when i try to visit the page,its show me 404 error and its duplicate 80 posts...

Comment: @Enuma `wp-load.php` is automatically connect db server.

Comment: Yes,but its duplicate 80 posts...and when i try to view the posts,its show me 404 error,the content of each posts is the img tag and the url of the images

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [wp_insert_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/), it will handle the prepared statement, validation and sanitization for you. If you are working outside WordPress you can easily load the WordPress core by requiring `wp-load.php`, and then insert posts using `wp_insert_post()`, more about in [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files).